# How can I use Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory, birational-geometry, line-bundles

For my research, I'm trying to understand how the Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch theorem is used in the paper [The Birational Geometry of the Hilbert Scheme of Points on Surfaces](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=The%20birational%20geometry%20of%20the%20Hilbert%20scheme%20of%20points%20on%20surfaces.&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) by Aaron Bertram & Izzet Coskun.

Throughout this paper, $X$ is a smooth projective surface over the complex numbers. $X^{[n]}$ denotes the Hilbert scheme parameterizing zero-dimensional schemes of length $n$. $X^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th symmetric product of $X$. $B$ is the class of exceptional divisors of Hilbert--Chow morphism.

On page 19, $L$ is assumed to be an ample line bundle on $X$. $L[n]$ is an induced line bundle on $X^{[n]}$.  Construction 2 induces a rational map
$$\phi_L \colon X^{[n]} \to G(N-n, N).$$
It is written that a straightforward calculation using the Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch theorem shows that the class of $\phi_L^{*}(\mathscr{O}_{G(N-n, N)} (1))$ is
$$\phi_L^{*}(\mathscr{O}_{G(N-n, N)} (1)) = L[n] - \frac{B}{2}.$$
I tried to figure out how to apply the GRR theorem but I still do not know.

Comment: I don't see how to do all of this off hand, but GRR is about pushforwards. So I can only assume that you are supposed to write the class in question as $aL[n] + bB$ for constants $a,b$, push it forward to the Grassmannian, and use GRR to obtain relations on $a$ and $b$ (the two divisors span Pic of the Hilbert scheme; I don't know if you know this, and I don't see it in the paper). However both sides of GRR look tricky to compute...